# I want to create a server in ubuntu that will run nodejs as the scripting laanguage

Tags: server, scripts, webserver, nodejs, port-forwarding

I want to run a node js instead of Php and want to make query from Android to access Database. But I am not getting a way to run the server from NodeJs in linux. I have a static IP in that specific IP I would like to run the server with NODE JS as the scripting language.

Comment: A node server (usually express) will be bind to a user-accesible port (1025+) since it should not be run as root. So your request should be made as `http(s)://{SERVER_IP}:{NODE_SERVER_PORT}/{PATH}/`. I will sugest you trying to use nginx as load balancer for your node server, that way you can have several instances running behing a single entry point with ssl eventually.

Comment: But that port is fixed and I can’t change the port to that specific port.

Comment: What i meant, is that you can access on port 80/443 and nginx will proxy the request to the node port